# How to change FROM address when workflow is configured in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

There is a requirement to change FROM address when workflow is configured in Sharepoint 2010 ?

By default it is static one and I want to change it so that site owners email adress will go as FROM address e.g sales@mycompany.com for sales site.

Pl suggest way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you use SharePoint designer at least?

Comment: designer may be used...

Comment: so you could deploy a custom workflow with the mail address that you need

Answer (score 1):

If you can use SharePoint designer you can dev your custom workflow and you can have what email address you want.

Comment: Hi Salvatore Di Fazio, you cannot do this through Designer 2010. we need some other approach .if you try u will understand. any one else pl reply.